# Search scores of the results from Azure Search explorer and Bot do not match

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-cognitive-search

I am searching the same text string from the chatBot which is passing this string to the azure search, but I am getting the results in a different order than the results appears in the azure search explorer from the Azure Portal.

Here is my search function for the azure search.

```
    module.exports = function () {
    global.request = require('request');

    global.searchQueryStringBuilder = function (query) {
        return queryString + query;
    }

    global.performSearchQuery = function (queryString, callback) {
        request(queryString, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var result = JSON.parse(body);
                callback(null, result);
            } else {
                callback(error, null);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

even if I print the queryString in the console and paste to the chrome browser, results are the same as the explorer. So kind of frustrating whats wrongs happening on the way. :(

Thanks in advance.
Vivek

Comment: Can you include the query string and the results you're receiving in your app and the Query Explorer so we can compare?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A full sentence is not being searched in the azure search but only a single word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51781654/a-full-sentence-is-not-being-searched-in-the-azure-search-but-only-a-single-word)

Comment: Are the scores actually different or are they just not sorted according to score? If they are are different, how much different are they?

Comment: They are completely different than the results from query explorer. however, they are sorted as per their score in the emulator.

Comment: @markB actually its quite different. If I search in explorer for the term "Fußnoten Löschen", I get the right document in the top first result with the score of 0.2520664, however, if I connect the same azure search to the bot and enter the same text in the emulator, I got totally different document with very low search score of Search Score: 0.004925617 and actual document doesn't even appear. Can you suggest me whats wrong?

Comment: Can you double check your setup for the Azure Search within your bot and show us? Specifically make sure that the index you're searching on checks out, but it'd be a good idea to audit everything.

Comment: Hi, @MarkB, yes I tried to make the URI using encodeURIComponent and now it is giving me similar results as the Azure search explorer. :)

Comment: @VivekJain could you post an answer with the code that allowed you to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Previously I was adding the URL parameters with the normal string operation +, so it was somehow sending something extra with the query. Following way to make the URL worked well and now azure search results and the results from code are in synch.

```
 var testUrl = global.queryString + 'api-key=' + encodeURIComponent(global['api-key']) + '&api-version=' + encodeURIComponent(global['api-version']) + '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(global.textToSearch);
```